# Iam adding the array in to the dictionary then remove the all objects from array

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

Iam adding the array in to the dictionary then remove the all objects from array.
When i print the dictionary it is also shows empty.Means the array data present in dictionary also removing.

```
if ([[[array objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[filteredAry objectAtIndex:j]])
{
    [menuAry addObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:i]];
}

[tempDict setValue:menuAry forKey:[filteredAry objectAtIndex:j]];
[menuAry removeAllObjects];
```

Why the tempdict shows empty?

Comment: have you initialized tempDict?

Comment: @joshua yes.. i have initialized

Comment: try putting an NSlog before you call removeAllObject and see if the object is there and put NSlog again after you call the removeAllObject just to confirm. if tempDict after that is empty at the end then @omz answer is what I think you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array you're adding to the dictionary is the very same object as the one you're removing all objects from. Adding it to the dictionary does not create a new object, it just adds a reference to the same object.

If you want to separate them, you should add a *copy* to the dictionary, like so:

```
NSMutableArray *copiedArray = [[menuAry mutableCopy] autorelease];
[tempDict setObject:copiedArray forKey:[filteredAry objectAtIndex:j]];
//...
```

If you use ARC, you can leave out the `autorelease`.